# ANGULAR 8 - how to pass the data in which the json inside of json

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-forms, angular-json

In angular 8
my json format to pass the data is like

```
 {
  "name": "",
  "address": {
    "line1": "",
    "pincode_id": ""
  }
}
```

I create the format to pass the data to submit the form

```
Format() {
    let data = this.Form.controls;
    let ctofclass = new type();
    ctofclass.name = data['name'].value;
    ctofclass.line1 = data.address['line1'].value;
    ctrofclass.pincode_id = data.address['pincode_id'].value.id;
    return ctofclass;
  }

class type {
  name: string;
  line1: string;
  pincode_id:any;
  
}
```

how to pass the data in which the json inside of json

when i use this format I got an error in this line below:

```
ctrofclass.line1 = data.address['line1'].value;
```

> core.js:6260 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

the address is inside of json and how to pass the data to submit the form

Comment: I assume `data` means that json in the first block? If it's literal json, then first you'll need to convert it to object (`JSON.parse(data)`)

Comment: {
  "name": "",
  "address": {
    "line1": "",
    "pincode_id": ""
  }
}   is the actual format that i have to pass ..... how to pass the data inside of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either set address as formGroup and line1 and pinecode_id as formControls or use just pinecode_id and line1 as separated formcontrols without grouping them inside address if address has no special value on itself.

Example using second solution (simplest):

```
CustomFormControl = formbuilder.group({
   name: [initialValue],
   pincode_id: [address.pincode_id] // mapping is done here
   line1: [address.line1]
})
```

Then You can access form values like this `CustomFormControl.controls[name].value`

Comment: but my code flow should be as a {
  "name": "",
  "address": {
    "line1": "",
    "pincode_id": ""
  }
}...... is that possile in that way (i.e     json inside of json )

Comment: That is the role of mapping. You can ensure you have the correct form after submition